# How to scale program to correct screen resolution?

Tags: java

I am putting on a concert at my university in the next forty minutes in which I am projecting a full screen application I wrote on several different screens. I was only able to get hold of the projection system tonight and low and behold when plugged in the resolution of my screen changes drastically but when I execute my program it works as if it is using my old screen resolution. I've coded the entire visual display to exact pixel values but now half of it isn't displaying as it is pushed off the side of the screen. I've tried changing my displays manually in system preferences but it has no effect. I've tried creating different display modes to fit the resolutions but I keep getting the message UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot change display mode. Is there anyway I can scale my program to the correct size or change to the correct display mode?

Below is the code I use to initialise the full screen:

```
            frame = new display();
            canvas = new Canvas();
            canvas.addKeyListener(this);
            frame.setUndecorated(true);
            frame.getContentPane().add(canvas);
            strategy = canvas.getBufferStrategy();
            environment = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
            device = environment.getDefaultScreenDevice();
            oldDisplay = device.getDisplayMode();
try {
            device.setFullScreenWindow(frame);
            newDisplay = new DisplayMode(1440, 900, 60, 60);
            device.setDisplayMode(newDisplay);
catch (Exception ex) { }
            canvas.requestFocus();
            canvas.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            canvas.createBufferStrategy(2);
            strategy = canvas.getBufferStrategy();
```

Display is just a direct extension of JFrame.

If I don't get this working I fail this module of my degree. Please stackoverflow don't fail me now! Thank you!

Edit: FIXED EXCEPTION however program seems to not be changing resolution at all despite setting things 800, 600, 60, 60.

Comment: If you've designed you application for a specific resolution then I doubt there is anything you really can do.  The only "real" chance you have is try and add a `AffineTransform` to scale the graphics from you designed resolution down to the expected resolution, but you need to add this to your paint routines.

Answer (score 2):

My solution is not something the OP is thinking about. But I believe it solves your problem.

Grab VirtualBox (or any other VM that supports Scale Mode). Spend 20 minutes install an operating system on that, and run your program inside it. Many VM supports scale mode, i.e. the guest OS will believe it's running resolution X<sub>1</sub>*Y<sub>1</sub>, but on your screen, it's actually displayed as X<sub>2</sub>*Y<sub>2</sub>, scaled by the VM. And therefore you can have your program display fine on whatever resolution.

Answer (score 0):

You can bump your DisplayMode down to (1024, 768, 60, 60) which most projectors will support. Worst case, drop it to 800, 600, 60, 60 - HOWEVER, anything drawn on your canvas with a hard coded pixel value outside of the DisplayMode range would no longer appear on the screen.

Comment: Changed it. However even at 800,600,60,60 there seems to be no visible change.